# Porque no se ejecuta mi setState en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo una duda y a la vez un problema con un proyecto en React, espero puedan ayudarme

Lo que pasa es que hay un formulario con un input de tipo texto y ese input tiene el evento onblur, onchange y onclick. Todo funciona bien en todos los eventos, menos en el onblur, porque cuando se ejecuta el evento onblur no pasa por el setState(), ya que al revisar el estado no tiene el que se le esta asignando, sino el anterior

El método que se ejecuta al ocurrir el evento onBlur tiene un if y adentro está un console.log() y el setState(), pero solo se ejecuta el console.log() pero no el **setState()**, y mi duda es porqué? a pesar de que entre al if no pasa por ese "setState()"

El código no lo puedo pasar por motivos de seguridad, pero pondré un ejemplo muy sencillo de cómo está el evento onBlur.

Cualquier sugerencia o aportación sería de mucha ayuda y se agradese mucho, ya que llevo una semana investigando porque no se ejecuta el setState()

Aquí pongo el ejemplo:

```
    Function Formulario (){
      Const {myState, setMyState}= useState()

Const handleBlur = () =>{
  if (condicion){
  Console.log("blur")
  SetMyState("se actualizo el estado"); 
}

}

return (
  <form>
   <Input type="text" onBlur={handleBlur}/>
</form>


)
    
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo identificas que no está funcionando? Coloca un ejemplo con todos tus eventos para poder reproducir exactamente lo que ocurre. Aun que estoy casi seguro que tu problema es que piensas que el setState se ejecuta de inmediato y eso no funciona así.

Comment: Si, no es muy claro lo que quieres preguntar... De donde sacas que se ejecuta el `console.log` pero no el `SetMyState`?

Comment: la solución es la S mayúscula de SetMyState ponla a minúscula cuando llamas el evento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por un lado estas llamando a la función setMyState con la primera en mayúscula, y por otro lado el useState devuelve un array no un objeto, osea que sería así:

```
Const [myState, setMyState] = useState()
```